# How to show column value as row and join data with other table?

Tags: sql-server

I want to categorize the data based on column values(Show column value as row)

This is how my table looks like

```
OfficeID   | Emp Name | Department  | Status
-----------+----------+-------------+--------
Office_1   |  Emp 1   | Marketing   | Active
Office_1   |  Emp 2   | Marketing   | Active
Office_1   |  Emp 3   | Marketing   | Non-Active
Office_2   |  Emp 4   | IT          | Active
Office_2   |  Emp 5   | Finance     | Active
Office_2   |  Emp 6   | Finance     | Non-Active
Office_2   |  Emp 7   | Finance     | Active
```

I want the result set to look like this

```
OfficeName | MarketingExecutive | FinanceExecutive | ITexecutive
-----------+--------------------+------------------+--------------
Office A   |         2          |        0         |     0
Office B   |         0          |        2         |     1
```

I want to give an alias name to the column name.

And the office value is coming from another table which has primary/foreign key relation with my above table

```
officeID  | OfficeName
----------+-----------
Office_1  | Office A
Office_2  | Office B
```

Update:

This is what I have tried so far

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT officeID,Department
     FROM EmpTable 
     WHERE Status = 'Active') AS SourceTable 
PIVOT
    (COUNT(Department) 
        FOR Department IN ([Marketing], [IT], [Finance])
    ) AS PivotTable;
```

I am not able to get the value from another table (`officeID => officeName`) and not able to set the alias name.

Also I am curious to know Is there any other way to do this without pivot

Comment: What have you tried so far? What you are after is a `PIVOT` or Cross Tab. There are 100's of examples of these on SO; have you have a look at any of them? How do you know someone is an Executive in the department, when there is no column to denote the position they hold?

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment.  You should try to write some SQL yourself; this is how you will learn to master the language.

Comment: I have updated the question and mentioned the part I have done

Comment: And what is teh problem with current query?

Comment: I suspect the lack of a `JOIN` to the other table, @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: I have mentioned the problem in the update

Comment: I appreciate the effort of everyone got the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a join of the tables, group by officename and conditional aggregation:

```
select 
  t2.officename,
  sum(case when department = 'Marketing' and status = 'Active' then 1 else 0 end) MarketingExecutive, 
  sum(case when department = 'Finance' and status = 'Active' then 1 else 0 end) FinanceExecutive,
  sum(case when department = 'IT' and status = 'Active' then 1 else 0 end) ITExecutive
from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2
on t2.officeid = t1.officeid
group by t2.officename
```

Or:

```
select 
  t2.officename,
  count(case when department = 'Marketing' and status = 'Active' then 1 end) MarketingExecutive, 
  count(case when department = 'Finance' and status = 'Active' then 1 end) FinanceExecutive,
  count(case when department = 'IT' and status = 'Active' then 1 end) ITExecutive
from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2
on t2.officeid = t1.officeid
group by t2.officename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7f28a7993c3594dd71914b8419c151c1).
Results:

```
> officename | MarketingExecutive | FinanceExecutive | ITExecutive
> :--------- | -----------------: | ---------------: | ----------:
> Office A   |                  2 |                0 |           0
> Office B   |                  0 |                2 |           1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT officeID, OfficeName, Department
     FROM EmpTable 
     Join OtherTable   -- add join
       ON EmpTable.OfficeID = OtherTable.OfficeName
     WHERE Status = 'Active') AS SourceTable 
PIVOT
    (COUNT(Department) 
        FOR Department IN ([Marketing], [IT], [Finance])
    ) AS PivotTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

THIS WILL DO IT

```
CREATE TABLE #TBL (OfficeID VARCHAR(20),Emp_Name  VARCHAR(20), Department  VARCHAR(20), [Status]  VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO #TBL VALUES
('Office_1','Emp 1','Marketing','Active'),
('Office_1','Emp 2','Marketing','Active'),
('Office_1','Emp 3','Marketing','Non-Active'),
('Office_2','Emp 4','IT','Active'),
('Office_2','Emp 5','Finance','Active'),
('Office_2','Emp 6','Finance','Non-Active'),
('Office_2','Emp 7','Finance','Active') 

SELECT
CASE WHEN OfficeID='Office_1' THEN 'Office A'
     WHEN OfficeID='Office_2' THEN 'Office B' END AS OfficeName 
,SUM(CASE WHEN Department = 'Marketing' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MarketingExecutive 
,SUM(CASE WHEN Department = 'Finance' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FinanceExecutive
,SUM(CASE WHEN Department = 'IT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ITexecutive

FROM #TBL
WHERE [Status] = 'Active'
GROUP BY CASE WHEN OfficeID='Office_1' THEN 'Office A'
     WHEN OfficeID='Office_2' THEN 'Office B' END
```

Comment: If for an office there is not any 'Active' status then this code will not return it in the results because of `WHERE [Status] = 'Active'`.

Comment: @forpas that is correct. Is that not what you want?